# Constructor Replacing Variables of Previously Created Objects

Tags: java, constructor

I'm not a strong programmer, and I'm just learning Java.  I'm running into a problem I haven't experienced before.  I've used constructors to create objects of a class before with no problem, but something odd is happening here.  I have a class Rational that is designed to represent fractions, and I've created the following constructor for it:

```
public Rational (int numerator, int denominator)
{
    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
}
```

Note that I have also initialized the int values numerator and denominator in the class.  I also had a bit of code in the class to keep the denominator from being zero, but I've removed it in my search to solve the problem.  Alas, it did nothing.

My problem comes when I try to test the class in a separate class file with a main method that utilizes this constructor.  For instance, if created two new rationals as follows:

```
Rational m = new Rational(2, 3);
Rational n = new Rational(5, 6);
```

Ive then tried to print these using a toString method I have in my class.  For reference, here is that method:

```
public String toString() {
    return numerator + "/" + denominator;
}
```

I'll print like this:

```
System.out.println(m);
System.out.println(n);
```

However, when I do this, the output I receive always refers to the Rational m and never to the Rational n.  That is, I receive the output:

5/6

5/6

(without the extra line of space between them).  This even happens when I try to print the numerators or denominators of each using my accessor methods in the class--it ALWAYS refers to the last Rational object created.

Interestingly, when I put the print line for m between the creation of rationals m and n, it works fine.  But I want to be able to refer to these rationals later in the program, so that isn't really a solution.

What am I doing wrong???  Why is my constructor failing to create objects with separate instance variables???

Comment: Do you know what `static` is?

Comment: My understanding of the static modifier is fuzzy... my professor hasn't really lectured on it.  I should note that my variables `numerator` and `denominator` in my class are declared using the static modifier.  Is that an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is. Read the tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Ah, thank you!  So, my misunderstanding of static was that it referred to variable types shared among objects of a class (e.g. every bicycle has a speed).  Now it's more clear that the static modifier refers to a variable for which the _value_ is the same for all members of the class (if that's an appropriate distinction).  I've changed the presence of the static modifiers in my class and it now works.